# how to create a cron job that resets the values in database after 30 days?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using PHP Codeigniter

I have tables users which has a field balance datetype is **ENUM('Yes','No')**. I also have a field called reset_date which stores the date when the user's balance is set to yes. So i want to count 30 days and after 30 days want to reset that user balance again to **No**. So for each user if his balance user is set to yes then i want to count 30 days and reset balance after 30 days.

i am storing the current date when Balance is set to yes by :

```
if($this->input->post('balance') === "Yes") 
        {

                $key= $this->session->userdata('key');
                $this->reseller_m->deduct($key);/// pass youe id here

                $this->load->helper('date');
                $this->db->set('reset_date',unix_to_human(now()));   
                $this->db->where('id',$id);
                $this->db->update('users', $data);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution:

You can do this without a cron job: just use on column called balance_timestamp which is a timestamp of when the field was set to yes. if it's not set (`null`), it means no.

Now, instead of `SELECT .. WHERE balance="Yes"`, just call `SELECT .. WHERE balance_timestamp>NOW()-30` which returns all items which were set to yes in the last 30 days

Alternatively, you could call your field `balance_validuntil` and set it to `NOW()+30`. This makes it easier to select: `SELECT .. WHERE balance_validuntil>=NOW()`

This is the code *for writing*.

```
if($this->input->post('balance') === "Yes") 
        {

                $key= $this->session->userdata('key');
                $this->reseller_m->deduct($key);/// pass youe id here

                $this->load->helper('date');
                $this->db->set('balance_validuntil',unix_to_human(now()+30));   
                $this->db->where('id',$id);
                $this->db->update('users', $data);
        }
}
```

For *selecting*:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('balance_validuntil >=', unix_to_human(now()));
```

Comment: can you please write down a sample code for me ? i dint understood.

Comment: but how will the balance set to no after 30 days?

Comment: i mean i want to check each user if his reset date is more than 30 days from the date set i want to set balance = No

Comment: after 30 days, balance_validuntil is automatically <NOW() which means no. you don't have to change the value. It's like your credit card's expire date. If it is 2015-11, your card doesn't self-destory in any way in november. it just gets outdated

Comment: But this is selecting data :P you wrote for reading but i want to update the balance back to no with that certain id . also how will system continously check every user's balance_validuntil

Comment: I thange the "selecting" :-). Again: you will not have to continuously check. In your question, you don't want to print/email/report those which you set to "no", so you just don't neet to do that. You will see when you select the next time that record disappeared from the result, that's it.

Comment: see my scenario is reseller add balance to user. so user has 30 days to use the balance once he completes 30 days from set to yes. his balance should again be no

Comment: maybe you're trying your best to make me understand but sorry m new to codeigniter and m not getting the logic :(

Comment: could you just take over team viewer and help me solve this

Comment: I never heard about codeigniter before. I'm only sharing my php and mysql knowledge... In this case you can just check if balance_validuntil is >NOW. if this is true, the balance of the user is 'yes' if balance_validuntil is NULL or balance_validuntil is <NOW then the balance is 'no'. I don't know how your code has to look like. My answer is only about the architectural solution.